# Plot with bar and line and two y axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes

I need to plot a bar chart showing counts and a line chart showing the average. This all in one chart with multiple y axes.

Here is an example of the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame("YearMonth" = c(20141, 20142, 20143, 20144), "Count" = c(435, 355, 360, 318), "Average" = c(107, 85, 86, 74))
```

How can this be done?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would like to have two different y axes. With on the left the count and an secondary on the right, the average.

Answer (score 1):

[{ggplot2} intentionally does not support this kind of multiple y-axes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/1968) because there’s a broad consensus that they are a bad idea because they invite misinterpretation of the data. See e.g. [*Why not to use two axes, and what to use instead*](https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/):

> We believe that charts with two different y-axes make it hard for most people to intuitively make right statements about two data series. We recommend two alternatives strongly: using two charts instead of one and using indexed charts.

The only kind of secondary y-axis that {ggplot2} supports is one that’s a scaling of the primary axis, see [`sec_axis`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html). Such a secondary axis doesn’t suffer from the same problem, but it won’t work in your scenario: what you want is indeed one of the cases that {ggplot2} intentionally doesn’t support.

What you *can* do, though, is to *duplicate* a single y-axis, and overlay the bars and the averages (although it’s not clear what the bars represent in this case):

```r
# fix the `YearMonth` column:
df$YearMonth = lubridate::ymd(paste(sub('(.)$', '0\\1', as.character(df$YearMonth)),'01'))

ggplot(df) +
    aes(YearMonth) +
    geom_col(aes(y = Count)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = Average), size = 2, color = 'lightblue') +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL))
```

[image: dual y-axis]